# SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[@class= ‘encontrados ng-star-inserted’]' is not a valid XPath expression

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, scrapy

I am getting syntax error.

**My Code:**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class= ‘encontrados ng-star-inserted’]')
```

I want to extract the text contained in this site's search result :

[Website Link](https://www.bcb.gov.br/estabilidadefinanceira/buscanormas?conteudo=risco&dataInicioBusca=01%2F06%2F2021&dataFimBusca=15%2F06%2F2021&tipoDocumento=Todos)

Comment: What text are you trying to extract?

Answer (score 0):

Lucas,

This answer assumes that you want to fetch text out of the website  :

```
print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//html/body").get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

I could not find `encontrados ng-star-inserted` class in the webapp that you have shared.

But if you want to retrieve the text which is in middle of the website, you can do this instead  :

```
for middle_text in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.resultado-item"):
    print(middle_text.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your locator is not correct.
Try this instead:

```
results = driver.find_element_by_css('div.encontrados').text
```

Or this

```
results = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class,"encontrados")]').text
```

`ng-star-inserted` is not a fixed class name there while `div` tag name with  `encontrados` class name are giving fixed unique identification of that element.
Also, your problem is with `'//div[@class= ‘encontrados ng-star-inserted’]'` xpath expression. You are trying to use `'` both for external and the internal string definition while you should use `'` for one and `"` for the other. I.e. or this:

```
`'//div[@class= "encontrados ng-star-inserted"]'`
```

or this

```
`"//div[@class= 'encontrados ng-star-inserted']"`
```

That's why you are getting the "is not a valid XPath expressing" error since  your syntax is not correct too.
So just use one of the expressions I used at the top:

```
results = driver.find_element_by_css('div.encontrados').text
```

Or this

```
results = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class,"encontrados")]').text
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! but when I tried these codes I got the following error: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.encontrados"}

Comment: Do you have some delay / wait before it?

Comment: No, the script crashes in this part.

Comment: So, maybe you should simply add some delay before that line to make the page loaded? Just try putting most simple delay like `time.sleep(10)` before `results = driver.find_element_by_css('div.encontrados').text`

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class= ‘encontrados ng-star-inserted’]')
```

you have invalid character ‘ enclosing the attribute value use any of:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class= "encontrados ng-star-inserted"]')   
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class= 'encontrados ng-star-inserted']")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class= \"encontrados ng-star-inserted\"]")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class= \'encontrados ng-star-inserted\']')
```

Comment: doesn´t work yet, even with these changes.